# Modal bootstrap open and close immediately

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I created a filter search in JavaScript to get orders from my app, but when the search get results, I click in modal panel and it open and close immediately, I searched about that and find something related about conflict in JavaScript.

Is not the first time what that happened, how to find this conflicts more fast? Is have a software about that? I try to use Fiddler, but I haved no success.

Thats is my code:

**Order view**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
@extends('admin/layouts/default')

{{-- Page title --}}

@section('title')
  Comércio Urbano - Pedidos
   @parent
@stop

{{-- Page level styles --}}

@section('header_styles')

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

@stop

{{-- Page content --}}
@section('content')
<section class="content-header">
  <!-- section starts -->
  <h1> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Pedidos</h1>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li>
          <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}">
              <i class="livicon" data-name="home" data-size="14" data-loop="true"></i>
              Início
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Pedidos </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">Listagem de pedidos</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="content">
<div class="row">
  <center>
  <table id="seachTable" style="margin: 1%;">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="marketplaceTitle">Marketplace</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="marketplace" id="marketplace">
          <option value="" @if(session('marketplace') === "") selected  @endif>Selecione</option>
          <option value="b2w" @if(session('marketplace') === "b2w") selected  @endif>B2W</option>
          <option value="Mercado Livre" @if(session('marketplace') === "Mercado Livre") selected  @endif>Mercado Livre</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="codigoprodutoTitle">Código (Produto)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoproduto" id="codigoproduto" value="{{ session('codigoproduto') }}">
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="codigopedidoTitle">Código (Pedido)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigopedido" id="codigopedido" value="{{ session('codigopedido') }}">
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="StatusTitle">Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="statusorder" id="statusorder">
          <option value="" @if(session('statusorder') === "") selected  @endif>SELECIONE</option>
            <option value="confirmed" @if(session('statusorder') === "confirmed") selected  @endif>CONFIRMADO</option>
            <option value="CANCELED" @if(session('statusorder') === "CANCELED") selected  @endif>CANCELADO</option>
            <option value="PROCESSING" @if(session('statusorder') === "CANCELED") selected  @endif>PROCESSANDO</option>
            <option value="NOT_APPROVED" @if(session('statusorder') === "NOT_APPROVED") selected  @endif>NÃO APROVADO</option>
            <option value="paid" @if(session('statusorder') === "paid") selected  @endif>PAGO</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="DataTitle">Data</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateaproved" id="dateaproved" value="{{ session('dateaproved') }}">
      </th>
      <th>
        <label for="TotalTitle">Total</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="totalorder" id="totalorder" placeholder="R$" value="{{ session('totalorder') }}">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="clean-form-button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 1%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" ></i> Limpar Filtro </button>
</center>
      <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="order-table">
            @include('admin.order-table')
          </div>
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
       </div>
</div>
</section>
@stop
@section('footer_scripts')
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#cover').fadeOut(1000);
    })
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/OrderSearch.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        var postPesquisa = '{{ route('order::pesquisaPost') }}';
        var pesquisaRequest = {
            'model': '{{ session('model') }}',
            'descricao':'{{session('descricao')}}',
            'distributor': '{{ session('distributor') }}',
            'status': '{{ session('status') }}',
            'stock' : '{{ session('stock') }}',
            'categoria' :'{{session('categoria')}}',
            'image' : '{{ session('image') }}',
        };
</script>
@stop
```

**Order-Table view**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class="modal-loader"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/master.css')}}" />
<center>
<h4>  <b style="color: #c0c0c0">{{$order->total()}} resultados</b> </h4>
</center>
<table class="table table-striped" style="padding: 1%;margin:1%; width: 97%">
        <tr>
            <th>Marketplace</th>
            <th>Codigo Produto</th>
            <th>Código Pedido</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Aprovação</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th style="width: 50px;">Relatório</th>
            <th>PDF</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($order as $orders)
            <tr>
                <td><span class="label label-primary">{{$orders->erp_marketplace}}</span></td>
                <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="codigoproduto" value="{{$orders->erp_createdid}}" style="max-width: 70%;" readonly> </td>
                <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="codigoproduto" value="{{$orders->erp_site}}" style="max-width: 70%;" readonly></td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">{{ App\Helpers\OrderStatusHelper::$status[$orders->erp_status]}}</span></td>
                <td>{{$orders->erp_orderaprove}}</td>
                <td>{{$orders->erp_orderquantity}}</td>
                <td>R${{$orders->erp_totalvalue}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="getCode" value="{{$orders->erp_createdid}}" />
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="getCode" value="{{$orders->erp_createdid}}" />
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger"  onclick= 'submitButton()' type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>PDF</button></td>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalhes</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      TESTE
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
</table>
```

**And my default layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        @section('title')
            Comércio Urbano - Administração
        @show
    </title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/css/painel.css"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- global css -->

    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- font Awesome -->

    <!-- end of global css -->
    <!--page level css-->
    @yield('header_styles')
            <!--end of page level css-->
</head>
<body class="skin-josh">
<header class="header">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" class="logo">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/logo.png') }}" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <div class="responsive_nav"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @include('admin.layouts._messages')
                @include('admin.layouts._notifications')
                <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        @if(Sentinel::getUser()->pic)
                            <img src="{!! url('/').'/uploads/users/'.Sentinel::getUser()->pic !!}" alt="img" height="35px" width="35px"
                                 class="img-circle img-responsive pull-left"/>
                        @else
                            <img src="{!! asset('assets/img/authors/avatar3.jpg') !!} " width="35"
                                 class="img-circle img-responsive pull-left" height="35" alt="riot">
                        @endif
                        <div class="riot">
                            <div>
                                <p class="user_name_max">{{ Sentinel::getUser()->first_name }} {{ Sentinel::getUser()->last_name }}</p>
                                <span>
                                        <i class="caret"></i>
                                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <!-- User image -->
                        <li class="user-header bg-light-blue">
                            @if(Sentinel::getUser()->pic)
                                <img src="{!! url('/').'/uploads/users/'.Sentinel::getUser()->pic !!}" alt="img"
                                     class="img-circle img-bor"/>
                            @else
                                <img src="{!! asset('assets/img/authors/avatar3.jpg') !!}"
                                     class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="User Image">
                            @endif
                            <p class="topprofiletext">{{ Sentinel::getUser()->first_name }} {{ Sentinel::getUser()->last_name }}</p>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Menu Body -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ URL::route('admin.users.show',Sentinel::getUser()->id) }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="user" data-s="18"></i>
                                My Profile
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', Sentinel::getUser()->id) }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="gears" data-s="18"></i>
                                Account Settings
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Menu Footer-->
                        <li class="user-footer">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <a href="{{ URL::route('lockscreen',Sentinel::getUser()->id) }}">
                                    <i class="livicon" data-name="lock" data-size="16" data-c="#555555" data-hc="#555555" data-loop="true"></i>
                                    Lock
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/logout') }}">
                                    <i class="livicon" data-name="sign-out" data-s="18"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
        <section class="sidebar ">
            <div class="page-sidebar  sidebar-nav">
                <div class="nav_icons">
                    <ul class="sidebar_threeicons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/product') }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="table" title="Produtos" data-loop="true"
                                   data-color="#418BCA" data-hc="#418BCA" data-s="25"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/tasks') }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="linechart" title="Finanças" data-loop="true"
                                   data-color="#FFF" data-hc="#FFF" data-s="25"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/gallery') }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="piggybank" title="Vendas" data-loop="true"
                                   data-color="#8FBC8F" data-hc="#8FBC8F" data-s="25"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/users') }}">
                                <i class="livicon" data-name="sky-dish" title="Integração" data-loop="true"
                                   data-color="#E0FFFF" data-hc="#E0FFFF" data-s="25"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU -->
                @include('admin.layouts._left_menu')
                <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU -->
            </div>
        </section>
    </aside>

    <aside class="right-side">
        <!-- Notifications -->
        @include('notifications')

                <!-- Content -->
        @yield('content')

    </aside>
    <!-- right-side -->
</div>
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" style="border-radius: 50%;"
   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
    <i class="livicon" data-name="plane-up" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#fff" data-hc="white"></i>
</a>
<!-- global js -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/summernote/0.5.0/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/painel.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
</script>
<!-- end of global js -->
<!-- begin page level js -->
@yield('footer_scripts')
        <!-- end page level js -->
</body>
</html>
```

I realy try to find this conflicts, but I not have success. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your foreach loop. Every table row has a button that targets the same modal id.

```
<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
</td>
```

Try appending the order id to the modal id and the modal idea and the button attribute that targets the modal to make them unique.

Better still, remove the modal from the table rows and only have one one the page then populate it with js when you click a table row.

Comment: I forgot that detail, thank you! But it's still conflicting.

Comment: What does `<div class="modal-loader"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>` do? Is there any scripts related to it that could trigger the close?

Comment: This modal opens to show that the research is being done, I removed it from the code, but it continues to give the same problem.

Comment: Strange, the modal opens normally before the search is done.